# MSAL Android B2C re-use cookies after login successful

Tags: android, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal

According to the [sample code](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-android-kotlin),I have added the configuration as follows

```
{
  "client_id": "my_client_id",
  "redirect_uri": "my_redirect_uri",
  "account_mode": "MULTIPLE",
  "authorities": [
    {
      "type": "B2C",
      "authority_url": "my_authority_url",
      "default": true
    }
  ],
  "logging": {
    "pii_enabled": true,
    "log_level": "ERROR",
    "logcat_enabled": true
  }
}
```

Also, I have added the activity `BrowserTabActivity` under `Androidmanifest.xml` as follows

```
    <activity
        android:name="com.microsoft.identity.client.BrowserTabActivity"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data
                android:scheme="msauth"
                android:host="my_host_name"
                android:path="my_path" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

I am able to log in with MSAL Android Library for B2C successfully. I believe that the `BrowserTabActivity` is finished after the login is successful.

I understand that it shores the cookies in its own cookie jar but I am not able to get access to it to reuse it next time.

How can I reuse these cookies which are generated from the login process above for my subsequent calls from another part of the native app?

(there is no proper documentation on these topics)